# How to remove inactivate conda environment names from jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, miniconda

I have created multiple miniconda environments in my macbook. But when I open jupyter notebook, it shows non-existent conda environments I created long ago and which are no longer available in conda environments.

How to remove these non-existing environment names from jupyter notebook?

## My current conda list

[image]

## What Jupyter Shows

(NOTE: For example, Jupyter notebook shows environment "xx" which is not in conda env list)

[image]

## How to remove non-existent environments

How to remove non existing environment such as "xx" from showing up when I open jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on how you registered the kernel, but I suspect you used the `python -m ipykernel install --user`. In that case, you should be able to get a list of where the kernels are registered with

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

and you can simply delete the folders corresponding to kernels you wish to delete.

It may be worth noting that using [`nb_conda_kernels`](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#nb_conda_kernels) to auto-register all Conda envs with `ipykernel` would automatically remove kernels when you delete their environments or remove the `ipykernel` from the environment.